# Matlab: How to create empty n*m matrix of arrays?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

How do I create a matrix of matrices?
I want to create a n*m matrix for which, each element is an array of three element. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way: google more about [Matlab's cell array](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html)

Another way: you can create a 3D (n-by-m-by-3) matrix, i.e: `m = zeros(n,m,3)`

Comment: thanks. But if I use  `m = zeros(n,m,3)` `m(1,1)` will give me 0 in stead of (0 0 0) which is what I actually wanted. Thanks.

Comment: then you should use cell array. With a 3D trick, you have access to m(i, j, 1) ... m(i, j, 3)

Comment: to have the whole (0,0,0) displayed, then you must have 3rd index using Matlab's vectorization: `m(i, j, :)`

Comment: How can I make modifications to the original matrix? I used: `a = zeros(2,2,3)`  `b = a(1,1,:)`  `b(3) = 3`, but this doesn't change the element in `a`. Because when I do `c = a(1,1,:)`   `c(3)`  it still gives me `0`.

Comment: of course, you must modify the original matrix directly, i.e `a(1,1,3) = 3`. If you do `b = a(1,1,:)`, then Matlab creates a copy of `a(1,1,:)` in memory, and names it `b`, hence a chance in `b` does not affect `a`.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you mean? 
use the built  in function zeros

example

a = zeros(N,M,P)

P = 3

Answer (score 1):

You could use `mat2cell`

but i would recommend using 3D matrix as the other answers suggests

```
m = 5;
n = 4;
A = randi(50,n,m*3);
out = mat2cell(A,ones(n,1),repmat(3,m,1));
```

Output:

```
>> out

out = 

[1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
[1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
[1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
[1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
[1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]
```

You could access each element with `{}` like this:

```
>> out{1,1}

ans =

 6    41    13
```

For creating empty cells,

```
>> out = cell(m,n)

out = 

[]    []    []    []
[]    []    []    []
[]    []    []    []
[]    []    []    []
[]    []    []    []
```